# How to end a quiz using java script timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a simple quiz application using simple HTML code and a JavaScript, I want the quiz to jump to the final score when the speculated time elapse. I have been able to set up the timer but its not executing what I really want and I don't know where to go from here. I will be so glad  if anyone can find time to look in it.

Comment: Please add your code, so we can find out what's wrong and help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout, that execute a code after a time.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp